# Heroku Help: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

First off my apologies as i am a complete noob.

I created a JS bot for Discord that rolls dice for our TTRPG group playing Weave.

The bot runs fine from my pc, and will run from GitHub on Heroku for a couple of minutes, and then throws an error: `Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes`.

**log:**

```
2020-05-14T06:08:44.097216+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2020-05-14T06:08:44.097217+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-14T06:09:42.647001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-14T06:09:42.651315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-14T06:09:46.654014+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-14T06:09:46.654028+00:00 app[web.1]: > discordweavedicebot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-14T06:09:46.654028+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2020-05-14T06:09:46.654029+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-14T06:10:44.626907+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2020-05-14T06:10:44.707304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've added a procfile making index.js a worker (per a suggestion on another thread)

**procfile:**

```
worker node index.js
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "discordweavedicebot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "eddgue",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const dieFaces = ["Fail","Brook","Gale","Stone","Flame","Weave"];

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content == '!Roll 1' || message.content == '!roll 1' || message.content == '!Roll1' || message.content == '!roll1' || message.content == '!R1' || message.content == '!r1'){
        message.reply("You rolled: " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    }

    if(message.content == '!Roll 2' || message.content == '!roll 2' || message.content == '!Roll2' || message.content == '!roll2' || message.content == '!R2' || message.content == '!r2'){
        message.reply("You rolled: " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    }

    if(message.content == '!Roll 3' || message.content == '!roll 3' || message.content == '!Roll3' || message.content == '!roll3' || message.content == '!R3' || message.content == '!r3'){
        message.reply("You rolled: " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    }

    if(message.content == '!Roll 4' || message.content == '!roll 4' || message.content == '!Roll4' || message.content == '!roll4' || message.content == '!R4' || message.content == '!r4'){
        message.reply("You rolled: " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    }

    if(message.content == '!Roll 5' || message.content == '!roll 5' || message.content == '!Roll5' || message.content == '!roll5' || message.content == '!R5' || message.content == '!r5'){
        message.reply("You rolled: " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    }

    if(message.content == '!Roll 6' || message.content == '!roll 6' || message.content == '!Roll6' || message.content == '!roll6' || message.content == '!R6' || message.content == '!r6'){
        message.reply("You rolled: " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + ", " + dieFaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    }
})

bot.login('XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

I think there are cleaner ways of achieving the same, but given my limited programming experience this was the best I could come up with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I think you need to start a server and listen to the port assigned to you by heroku in PORT env, otherwise heroku will consider your web application dead and terminate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You server need to listen to a port from heroku,
 i will advise you do something like this.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

or maybe you should try setting the walker

```
heroku ps:scale worker=0
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm no longer getting the `Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes`.  

But the app still crashes after a couple of minutes. 

**Log:**

`2020-05-14T12:43:19.727186+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-14T12:43:19.727204+00:00 app[web.1]: > discordweavedicebot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-14T12:43:19.727204+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2020-05-14T12:43:19.727205+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-14T12:44:17.169097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: I tried setting the walker with no success, same result with both codes.

`Eduardos-MBP:discord-weave-dice-bot Eddgue$ heroku ps:scale worker=0
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.35.0 to 7.41.1.
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (worker).
Eduardos-MBP:discord-weave-dice-bot Eddgue$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.35.0 to 7.41.1.
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (worker).`

Comment: Did you test this locally? 
And was it working properly without crashing after some minutes?